# Por qué, al quitar border de un div, el div se mueve?

Tags: css

Al momento de quitar un border:1px solid red a un div ; el div se cambia de posicion y se mueve un poco, pero cuando no quito el border , se queda en su posicion original , quisiera saber a que se debe ?

```
.content-zoom {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    align-items: center;
    height: inherit;
    overflow: hidden;

    // border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Comment: Recuerda compartir el código para que podemos ayudarte mejor

Comment: Hola. Un gusto, Miguel Angel. Explicate un poco mejor. Al cambiar el border, se  mueve 1px? Eso sería normal.¿Podrías poner el código html también? Tené en cuenta que el comentario con // (doble barra) no funciona en css. Por ahí es ese tu problema. Probá de comentar con /*  */

Answer (score 1):

Le estas quitando 1 pixel por cada lado al elemento, esto puede suponer que el contenedor se mueva, dependiendo del tamaño del contenedor, el de los elementos contigüos, el displa aplicado...

Puedes mantener el tamaño de la caja como si mantuviera su borde ajustando su ancho: `width: 400px;` a `width: 402px;`.
Sin embargo, lo que se suele hacer para evitar que el ancho de un borde por ejemplo afecte al espacio que ocupa un elemento es usar la propiedad `box-sizing`, p.e. como parte del reset de estilo, al inicio del CSS:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing  : border-box;
    margin      : 0;
    padding     : 0;
}
```

Como ha dicho @Federico_Saenz en el comentario en CSS no se puede poner un comentario de este tipo:

```
// esto es un comentario erroneo en CSS
```

Tendrías que hacerlo así:

```
/* esto es un comentario en CSS */
```

El comentario en línea solo es válido si estas usando pre-procesadores como LESS o  SASS.